# Short Time Fourier Transform has different frequencies than Fourier Transform?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, audio, stft, statistics

The reason we do the STFT is so that we can analyse for short segments of time how much of the components in the frequencies of the FT are present. However, it may be possible that completely different frequencies are used to approximate the curve in this window that were used by the FT for the global curve.

In this case, we are assigning frequencies to segments we know our signal does not really have but are an artefacts of our sampling rate and hop length. Even different window functions may give very different spectrums. Is this not a big problem? How do we go around interpreting the outputs or circumventing this issue?

Comment: (F)FT itself is full of artifacts, far from an ideal reference; STFT can be lot more accurate with proper window selection. See [demo](https://overlordgolddragon.github.io/test-signals/).